# How to see discriminated conversion count in google adwords?

Tags: google-analytics, report, google-ads-api

I'm using adWords and trying do a deep analysis of revenue on a account with several campaigns and various obejctives. But I don't seem to find my way.
I need to find out the way to see the total for each objective by campaign, add or keyword.

> Example: for a given campaing there where N conversions for Objective
>   1, N for objective 2, and so on.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use a segment: On the toolbar just above the chart there's a drop-down box for segments, select `Segments > Conversions > Conversion Action Name` or `Segments > Conversions > Conversion Tracking Purpose`, and you should be able to see what you're looking for.